# Call C++ constructor of base class with same arguments

Tags: c++, constructor

I've ve something like this:

```
class A {
public:
  A(int a1,int a2,int a3) {
  }
}
class B: public A {
public:
  B(int a1,int a2,int a3) : A(a1,a2,a3) { 
     .. Do Some More Init for B ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write the constructor in a a shorter form? 
The Constructor of the base class should be called with the same arguments. But I don't want to list all of the arguments explicit. And I need to do some special initialization stuff for class B.

I think something like this:

```
class B: public A {
public:
  B(int a1,int a2,int a3) : A(...AUTOARG...) { 
    .. Do Some More Init for B ...
  }
}
```

Is this possible in C++/11?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no code happening inside `B`'s constructor and you simply want to allow its construction in the same ways `A` is constructible, you can *inherit* `A`'s constructors:

```
class B: public A {
public:
  using A::A;
};
```

This will give `B` all the same constructors as `A` has.

If, as the edited question says, `B`'s constructor is not empty, you can still get "do all `A` does plus some more" in a generic (but not as nice) way using a "catch-all" constructor with perfect forwarding:

```
class B: public A {
public:
  template <class... Arg>
  B(Arg&&... arg) : A(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...) { 
     //.. Do Some More Init for B ...
  }
}
```

Note that this changes `B`'s behaviour slightly with respect to type traits. It now seems constructible from anything, but using incorrect arguments will fail to compile. If you also need the class to play nice with constructibility detection traits etc., you can conditionally disable the incorrect instantiations using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Comment: Thanks. but I need some init in constructor B. see my edit.

Comment: @powerpete: It's naughty to change the question in such a material way; for one it invalidates this answer.

Comment: @powerpete That should have been part of the original question. Nevertheless, I've provided a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Better still, *inherit* the constructor. This is a new feature from C++11:

```
class B: public A {
public:
  using A::A;
};
```

Unfortunately though, if you want the `B` constructor to do additional things, then you'll need to write it out longhand as you currently do.